# Is there a group by * except [col name] in sql

Tags: sql

I have a very fat table with more than 100 columns. I want to count the number of value of one column. But in order to do that I have to group by all the other columns (which is a pain). Is there a way to group the table by all the columns except for that one?

It works like:

```
select * [except col],count(col) 
from table
group by * [except col];
```

The table is like:

```
(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9.....,Col100)
(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6......,X)
(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6......,Y)
(1,0,2,2,3,4,5,6......,X)
(1,0,2,2,3,4,5,6......,X)
(1,0,2,2,3,4,5,6......,Y)
(1,0,2,2,3,4,5,6......,Z)
```

result should be

```
(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6......,2)
(1,0,2,2,3,4,5,6......,4)
```

Comment: Um, nope.  You can use dynamic sql or you'll need to write the columns out.  The dynamic sql approach would be rdbms specific, so please provide if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I know that in sql server you can drag and drop columns in management studio,and many clients for mysql offer the same.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm remotely connected to the server through putty. It seems that I might need to type in all the column names.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Gordon, if you still want to try the traditional way and don't want to mention 100 columns.

Try this:

```
declare @Colsql Nvarchar(Max)

Select @ColSql = isnull(@ColSql + ',','') + '['+c.name+']'
from sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c
on t.object_id = c.object_id 
inner join sys.schemas sc
on t.schema_id = sc.schema_id
Where t.name = @TableName and sc.name = @SchemaName
and c.name <> @ColumnToExclude

Exec('Select ' +@ColSql+ 'Count(@ColumnToExclude) From @TableName Group By '+@ColSql)
```